# Delphi TMapView disabled auto zoom

Tags: android, delphi

On android with my TMapView I show the user location. When I move to the map may be 1 or 2 seconds after the TMapView automatically move to the user current position.

How to disable this "auto move to user location" ?

Comment: I have no experience with TMapView but based on available properties of this component I assume your location is being updated by some other code. Most likely from events of LocationSensor

Comment: The location can be update, but if for exemple my location is in Berlin and check Paris on the Map, I don't want that the view move to Berlin each time I move far of my location

Comment: That is why you need to prevent `LocationSensor` from updating location of your `MapView` until you press "MyLocation" button on the map view. So create yourself a boolean value. Set its value to False every time you drag the map location. Set it to True when you click on "MyLocation" button on your `MapView`. And then in your `LocationSensor` `OnLocationChanged` even check the value of that boolean variable. If it is true update the map location if False don't.

Comment: Thanks I understand :)